# CodeIgniter + MAMP : unable to send emails

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, mamp

I am trying to send emails with CI running on MAMP free. But it doesn't work, my script is encountering an infinite loop and nothing is happening...
Do i need to set up something especially to send emails from localhost?

Here is my email config for CI:

```
    $config = array();
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
    $config['smtp_user'] = '*****@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '******';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']  = '\r\n';
```

Cheers

EDIT: Here is my code to send an email:

```
    $config = array();
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
    $config['smtp_user'] = '****';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '*****';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']  = '\r\n';

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('****');
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject($title);
    $this->email->message($content);

    $this->email->send();

    error_log($this->email->print_debugger());
```

With $title, $content and $email vars defined in another part of my script. Don't worry about this stuff, I've already checked that my issue is not due to these.

Comment: Well, always the same question: _what do the log files say?_

Comment: Oh, and a side note: don't send html based email unless it really is neccessary. You ask unlimited trust from all receipients, since html emails open huge security issues. Plain text is absolutely sufficient for 99.9% of all messages.

Comment: Don't worry about html, it's just a test here.
As I said, I got an infinite loop, there is nothing printed (either returns from $this->email->send() or $this->email->print_debugger()) in the log, and nothing in the mail log of postfix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

**Send emails with MAMP (mail() PHP function)**

1. Set up SSL: http://soundsplausible.com/2012/01/14/enable-ssl-in-mamp-2-0-5/
2. Set up Postfix: http://benjaminrojas.net/configuring-postfix-to-send-mail-from-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/
3. Into MAMP's php.ini (glance phpinfo() to know which version is used and conclude into which folder you need to edit), comment lines **SMTP**, **smtp_port** and **sendmail_from**. Uncomment line **sendmail_path** and set **/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i** as new value.

You should be able to send emails now, if PostFix works fine (run test given in tutorial above).

**Send emails with CI**

To send emails with CI, you don't need to write your logins into a file for PostFix. However, you need to be able to run PostFix and SSL.

Here is an example of config file for a google account:

```
    $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_port'] = "587";
    $config['smtp_user'] = "*****";
    $config['smtp_pass'] = "*****";
    $config['smtp_crypto'] = "tls"; //very important line, don't remove it
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = "5"; //google hint
    $config['mailtype'] = "text";
    $config['charset']  = "utf-8";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Be careful with " " which are necessary, ' ' could create issues. Here I'm using a TLS connection. If you prefer SSL, use port 465 and fix correctly smtp_crypto value.

Answer (score 1):

You need use `sendmail`([details how install it on MAMP](http://www.blog.tripleroi.com/2012/05/solvedenabling-sendmail-on-localhost.html)). Or you can use solution below to store emails in localhost(something like emulate email sending).
I'm use this solution on my localhost(XAMPP). Maybe it will be helpful for you.

Specify path for send mail in `php.ini`

```
sendmail_path = "path/to/php path/to/sendmail.php"
```

The second step - you can try to use this script

```
    define('DIR','path/to/sendmail_dir');
    $stream = '';
    $fp = fopen('php://stdin','r');
    while($t = fread($fp,2048)){
        if($t === chr(0)){
            break;
        }
        $stream .= $t;
    }
    fclose($fp);

    $fp = fopen(mkname(),'w');
    fwrite($fp,$stream);
    fclose($fp);

    function mkname($i=0){
       $fn = DIR.date('Y-m-d_H-i-s_').$i.'.eml';
       if (file_exists($fn)){
           return mkname(++$i);
       }   
       else{
           return $fn;
       }
   }
```

Comment: I tried to configure my php.ini but it still doesn't work, although a command line such as 'echo "test" | mail -s "subject" email@host.ext' works fine.

Comment: Also, please, add your code for sending email. You can use ``$this->email->print_debugger()`` for debug

Comment: Glance comments above ;)

Comment: Can login to your google account? Sometimes google block account and when you login to gmail - show a Captcha.

Comment: Try use ``smtp.gmail.com`` instead ``smtp.googlemail.com``. All settings details you can see here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287

Comment: Thanks for your help joni_jones.
Yes, I can log to my google account. Ok, now I've got some errors into my log:
The following SMTP error was encountered: Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Unable to send email using PHP SMTP.  Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.